# How to pad the tmux messages by one space to the left?

Tags: tmux

I am talking about that messages what you get when there is only one window and You try to switch the the next window by pressing `C-b n`:

[image]

It prints as

```
|No next window
|
|
```

but I want it as

```
| No next window
|
|
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Just a reflex, please never mind me if it's off: you're trying to do that to work around a terminal emulator or a windowing system that doesn't give you enough margin around your actual terminal, so that you can't read all the things printed there? If that's the case, it might make more sense to ask how to fix that, instead!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, this behavior isn't harming in any practical way, You are right. But i dont like it's look and ask for help.

Comment: why don't you ask for help making your terminal emulator window have a useful behaviour? Why change the *content* you're displaying, if what you really want is the *form* of the window changed?